# VueJS - Difference between passing function name and call

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, frontend

Let's say we got an element with @click. What is the real difference between passing to it function by it's name and using it's call since both ways are working. Does it creates another abstraction level underhood for the call? Is one way preferred?

```
<element @click="functionName"></element>
<element @click="functionName()"></element>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use its name, the Event object is passed to the function. This is useful if you need to get at the event.target.

```
<element @click="functionName"></element>

functionName(x){
    console.log(x)
}

output (example as it'll change based on the event):
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 494, screenY: 88, clientX: 494, clientY: 22, …}
```

If you reference the full function call, you are explicitly declaring what is passed to the function.

```
<element @click="functionName()"></element>

functionName(x){
    console.log(x)
}

output:
undefined
```

Or again with something defined:

```
<element @click="functionName('foo')"></element>

functionName(x){
    console.log(x)
}

output:
foo
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My question was rather, what is going on underhood, when you don't have/use any arguments in your function. Like, is calling the function only by it's name faster?

Comment: I am not aware of any significant performance difference. If there is a difference, it is likely incredibly small. You should use whichever one you need to call the function. If I am not using the event, then I just use ().